# how to make nginx output log in screen like webrick and thin default mode without -d flag

Tags: nginx

Something for debugging reason, I check the log information very often, I may help to make the  log file directly output in screen line by line like webrick does

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal type 
    tail -f log/development.log
after you start nginx and be sure to type in your project directory